# Javascript Date Modifiying

Tags: javascript, function, date

I have written these two javascript functions:

```
function getDateFromDateAtHourOfDay(date, hour)
{
    var year = date.getFullYear();
    var month = date.getMonth();
    var day = date.getDate();

    var newDate = new Date(year, month, day, hour, 0, 0);

    return (newDate);
}
```

and

```
function getDateDescriptionFromDate(date)
{
    var year = date.getFullYear();
    var month = date.getMonth();
    var day = date.getDate();

    return ( (day < 10 ? ("0" + day) : (day)) + "." + (month < 10 ? ("0" + month) : (month)) + "." + year); 
}
```

The first one should return a new date with the same year/month/day but with a different hour of the day (e.g. switch 2015-04-05 15:00 to 2015-04-05 16:00).

The second one should just return a date-string in the format dd.MM.yyyy.

Now if I call

```
var selectedDate = new Date();   // normally function parameter
var startDate = getDateFromDateAtHourOfDay(selectedDate, hour);
document.getElementById("dateLabel").innerHTML = getDateDescriptionFromDate(startDate);
```

Where hour is a function parameter and for example 15 (tested with alert), in my "dateLabel" it says 05.01.2015. But if I do

```
alert (selectedDate);
```

the result is: Sun Apr 05 2015 15:52:26 GMT+0200 (CEST) => now.

`selectedDate` is not modified between the calls (alert and set the innerHTML).

I think the two functions do not do what I suppose them to, but maybe you find the mistake. 
Thank you !

**EDIT:**

I tried this code:

```
selectedDate = new Date();
alert(selectedDate);    // Sun Apr 05 2015 16:36:07 GMT+0200 (CEST)

var startDate = getDateFromDateAtHourOfDay(selectedDate, hour);
alert(hour);            // 8
alert(startDate);       // Thu Mar 05 2015 08:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)

document.getElementById("datumLabel").innerHTML = getDateDescriptionFromDate(startDate);        // 05.01.2015
```

Comment: Your dateLabel prints the value for startDate variable which is different than selectedDate. selectedDate variable is created as new Date() and is not being modified.

Comment: yes, but as you can see startDate is created through the function call of getDateFromDateAtHourOfDay(**selectedDate**, hour);

Comment: Correct so if you alert the same variable being used by the label which is (startDate), you will get the same value

Comment: I tried different things, see **EDIT**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you're surprised by what `selectedDate` is returning. You have only set it to `new Date()` (now). Nothing in the code is manipulating this variable from the point of creation.

You are, however, manipulating the value and storing the change in `startDate` and `dateLabel.innerHTML`. You would only notice the formatting though since the second function strips any change in "time" (done by the first function).

So, in short: You create a date (now), change the time, then format it to only show date.

```
var selectedDate = new Date();
//selectedDate value = the date and time right now
var startDate = getDateFromDateAtHourOfDay(selectedDate, hour);
//startDate value = whatever selectedDate was + hours sent as parameter
document.getElementById("dateLabel").innerHTML = getDateDescriptionFromDate(startDate);
//Formatted value of startDate, to only show date
```

**As per comment:**

You're missing that `month` in javascript is zero-based. So you'll have to do something like:

```
var month = date.getMonth() + 1; //in the second function
```

```js
function getDateFromDateAtHourOfDay(date, hour)
{
    var year = date.getFullYear();
    var month = date.getMonth();
    var day = date.getDate();

    var newDate = new Date(year, month, day, hour, 0, 0);

    return (newDate);
}

function getDateDescriptionFromDate(date)
{
    var year = date.getFullYear();
    var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    var day = date.getDate();

    return ( (day < 10 ? ("0" + day) : (day)) + "." + (month < 10 ? ("0" + month) : (month)) + "." + year); 
}

var selectedDate = new Date();   // normally function parameter
var startDate = getDateFromDateAtHourOfDay(selectedDate, 15);
document.getElementById("dateLabel").innerHTML = 'Your current system date: ' + getDateDescriptionFromDate(startDate);
```

```html
<div id="dateLabel"></div>
```

Comment: That's all true, and I knew this, but why does it show the wrong date in my dateLabel ?

Comment: I don't know (yet) why your result is that much off, but one thing is that month in javascript is zero-based. So when you do `var month = date.getMonth();` you'll have to increase it with 1.

Comment: okay, thank you ! now with `getMonth() +1` it works, but I'm still wondering why it then shows month "01" instead of one less: "03" :D

Comment: If you used the exact same code as you posted here, it shouldn't be possible (well, unless your system date is off) :)

Answer (score 0):

If you try this, this should give you save value for your alert and Label, the value you are using for the Label is different than the value you are trying to use alert on.

```
selectedDate = new Date();
alert(selectedDate);    // Sun Apr 05 2015 16:36:07 GMT+0200 (CEST)

var startDate = getDateFromDateAtHourOfDay(selectedDate, hour);
alert(hour);            // 8
alert(startDate);       // Thu Mar 05 2015 08:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)

var startDateDesc = getDateDescriptionFromDate(startDate); 
alert(startDateDesc)    // 05.01.2015
document.getElementById("datumLabel").innerHTML = startDateDesc; // 05.01.2015
```

Comment: the alert is just for test and demonstration purposes, the problem is that my label does not show the right time according to selectedDate or startDate

Comment: aah.. My bad but as Mackan jsfiddle shows that the value is showing up correctly (05.04.2015)